# In a CucumberBDD project org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector OR org.assertj.core.api.JUnitSoftAssertions are not catching error in spite of mismatch

Tags: junit, junit4, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, assertj

```
 @Rule
    public ErrorCollector errorCollector = new ErrorCollector();
 
  public void verifyDeviceType(String device_Type){
        System.out.println(deviceType.getText()+","+device_Type);==> camera,camera1
        errorCollector.checkThat("Expected Device Type Not Present.",deviceType.getText(),equalTo(device_Type));
    }

    public void verifyDeviceStatus(String device_Status){
        System.out.println(deviceStatus.getText()+","+device_Status);==>Might be offline,Online2
        errorCollector.checkThat("Expected Device Status Not Present.",deviceStatus.getText(),equalTo(device_Status));
    }
```

As shown above, first method should fail because camera vs. camera1 difference.
Second method should fail because 'Might be offline' Vs Online2 word difference, which I am expecting to be equal.
But ErrorCollector runs smoothly with out any complaints showing all the tests as passed.

***BTW, lastly, even if it shows them as errors, how do we access the messages or errors stored in the ErrorCollector, say in the next method, the third method after these two methods ran through collecting errors ?***

Then again, after learning about JUnitSoftAssertions, I tried

```
@Rule
    public JUnitSoftAssertions softAssertions = new JUnitSoftAssertions();
public void verifyDeviceType(String device_Type){
    System.out.println(deviceType.getText()+","+device_Type);==> camera,camera1
    softAssertions.assertThat(deviceType.getText()).as("Expected Device Type").isEqualTo(device_Type);
}



 public void verifyDeviceStatus(String device_Status){
        System.out.println(deviceStatus.getText()+","+device_Status);==>Might be offline,Online2
        softAssertions.assertThat(deviceStatus.getText()).as("Expected Device Status").isEqualTo(device_Status);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A reproducible test case would be great if you want people to help you.

I'm not sure to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve, are you looking for a report of all failed assertions? Your code samples don't show any tests methods (that is annotated with `@Test`), anyway for the AssertJ question, you can access collected errors with [assertionErrorsCollected](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractSoftAssertions.html#assertionErrorsCollected()).

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am trying to see if it is possible for a single Cucumber 'Then' step can accommodate multiple assertions. Apparently as per my above tests it can't be. If you are using JUnit's Assert.assertEqual or assertTrue methods, the test stops at the first failure. But I want test to continue showing what are all the assertions that had failed.

Comment: You can with soft assertions, they were created for that exactly.
https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-soft-assertions